# Webservice with Clientcertificate gives error Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel when running in IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, ssl, x509certificate

I have the following code to access a webservice using a Client certificate. All seems to work fine when I run this code in a console application. If I try to run it from a web application running in IIS 7. I get the error  "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

This is the code :

```
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls; //from other stackoverflow case
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true; //from other stackoverflow case
            db2wsService service = new db2wsService();
            service.Url = this.WebserviceUrl;                

            HttpServerUtility server = HttpContext.Current.Server;
            X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate(server.MapPath(this.CertificatePath), this.CertificatePassword);

            service.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

            service.PreAuthenticate = true;  
//do some stuff here to call webservices
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same encountered problem. this solution is winhttpcertcfg. if you search about using on the google , you will find it.

Comment: Can you expand a little on how it solves the problem? A short code example would be nice. "google it" is not a very nice answer, by the way.

Comment: okay first you have to install winhttpcertcfg.exe.This is link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19801
after you should write commondline as follows

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools>winhttpcertcfg -i "your certificate" -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -a "domain\username" -p "your certificate pass"

I hope you could help